# Primeflex variables $lg

Tags: sass, primeflex

in Primeflex docs, variable $lg (Breakpoint of screens such as notebook monitors) has a default value of 992px. How can I change that? For example, I want to set a default value of 1100px. Please assist  I'm using Primeflex 3.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in https://www.primefaces.org/primeflex/setup

> ### Variables
>
> SASS variables are available to customize and create your own primeflex build. To begin with clone the [primeflex repo](https://github.com/primefaces/primeflex) and then build the primeflex.scss file after your customizations. Refer to [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/install) documentation for more information about how to build scss files.

What is not super clear from that section is where to find the variables. You'll need to modify this file:

https://github.com/primefaces/primeflex/blob/master/_sass/lib/src/_variables.scss

Answer (score 3):

these steps solved my problem, thank you :)

1. Clone project from https://github.com/primefaces/primeflex
2. Change the values of variables on path _sass/lib/src/_variables.scss
3. Install sass globally with command npm install -g sass
4. Open the project
5. Run npm install to install packages
6. Run npm run build-lib which will create new dist folder
7. Copy dist folder into the ongoing project
8. Remove "primeflex": "3.0.1" from package.json file
9. Add path for using imported primeflex.css in angular.json file ("styles": [  "/primeflex/primeflex.min.css"  ])

Answer (score 0):

You might not want to modify anything because if it gets updated your modifications will be gone. Use an override to accomplish this. Add the following to your .scss

```
$lg:992px !important;
```

Comment: Hello, so, if I add $lg:1100px !important; to my scss file, I will override the standard value of lg from 992px to 1100px?

Comment: does it worked for you ? i have tried it but nothings happened :/

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to change my primeflex import to use the scss file rather than the CSS.